# How to prove that invoices are really unpaid?

Tags: united-states, banking, small-business, money-transfer, law

When it comes to official business documentation (USA) between a company and a client who is *either* another company (B2B) or individual person (B2C), how can the company providing the invoices, prove that those invoices are really not yet paid?

Passed due date is obviously insufficient proof. Also payer's (client's) bank account statement, with missing relevant line(s), is insufficient as well because the payer could have paid with a different bank account.

What else could be done here? Is there any official definition of such USA document and where could I get it?

Answer (score 106):

## You can't prove a negative.

Therefore, you cannot prove that an invoice is unpaid; it is assumed to be unpaid on claiming so, and *the payer* has to prove that he paid. That should be easy for him, if they did pay.

Comment: Hence, why you, as payer, need to ask for receipts, cancellation of the invoice (e.g. a "paid" stamp) or retain proof of payment (cancelled checks or bank transaction statements).

Comment: +1, however you could theoretically prove the negative here. For example, production of a contract that states payment must be made to a particular bank account, and bank statements showing that no such payment was ever received there.

Comment: I had to deal with a company that tried to claim I did not pay.  I pulled out my bank statement showing otherwise and he had nothing to say.

Comment: I had a recurring monthly cable internet bill; one month the amount credited was less than the actual cashed check. But the company claimed that any check I showed them was one credited in a different month, so it was tremendously difficult to fix. (Since then I always memo the specific bill date/ID on all my checks.)

Comment: It's perfectly possible to [prove a negative](https://departments.bloomu.edu/philosophy/pages/content/hales/articles/proveanegative.html).

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I am genuinely amazed that anyone pays for a monthly recurring bill by cheque! In the UK cheques are now extremely rare; some places do not accept them at all, and banks rarely issue chequebooks unless you explicitly ask for one.

Comment: Seriously, could you *please* edit or remove the title? Especially with "obviously", since, well, it *is* wrong.

Comment: @EricDuminil it might be wrong in strict mathematical or philosophical sense (although you didn't link to any proof it is), but it is generally true in this particular situation, in this particular context - unless method of payment is specified (not always is), and is perfectly traceable without the chance of error (in practice never is), you can't prove a lack of payment beyond all doubt. With high probability, maybe, but that's it.

Comment: @Mołot the linked article explains it better than I could. "you can't prove a negative" is itself a negative, so how would you prove it if it's indeed true? You're right, the content and explanation are perfectly correct. I just don't think that false claims should be written in bold letters.

Comment: -1 just for "Obviously, you can't prove a negative." That's misleading and perpetuates a common myth, even if it is the case you cannot prove the non-existence of payment in this case. "It's not hot" is easy to prove with a thermometer reading, "it's not past 5:00" is easy to prove with a clock, etc. Non-existence can be substantially harder to prove than negative statements in general, but is still possible with certain constraints. Almost any negative statement can be rephrased as a positive: "prove it was not paid" == "prove it is still unpaid", but that doesn't mean nothing is provable.

Comment: I kept thinking this seemed backwards, but the invoice itself satisfies 'the burden of proof'.

Comment: @Eric Wow that article linked is incredibly terrible.  It reads like something a first year philosophy student would write, utterly terrible logic used, particularly the unicorn example.

Comment: @JBentley: "In the US, checks are still very popular for paying rent and are also highly used by the payroll departments of many organisations. The financial infrastructure of many US companies is built around the usage of checks." E.g., I'm not sure my landlord would accept any other form of payment for rent.  https://www.cashbook.com/check-payments-in-the-uk-and-usa-in-2019/

Comment: @DanielR.Collins There's incorrect information in that webpage you cited. The "Checks in the USA" section heavily implies that cheques are superior to ACH which is nonsense because most banks in the US process cheques using ACH in the first place.

Comment: @eps sure, it's not really serious. The point still stands, though. ;)

Comment: @StevenJackson It is indeed impossible to prove a negative, if you're talking about a true negative rather than simply restating a condition. Proving something is not hot is the same as proving that it is cold and proving that it's not past 5 is the same as proving it is before 5. Your argument is as vacuous as saying "well, I can't prove I *didn't not* pay it"... Proving that something did not occur is impossible, which is what is meant by the phrase in question.

Comment: @scatter: Sorry, but your argument doesn't hold at all. I don't know how else to put it : please read some more about mathematics and logics.

Comment: @EricDuminil Are you saying that it's possible to prove that an event did not occur? Because that is my point. If so, please tell us how it can be done.

Comment: @scatter George Washington never walked on Pluto.

Comment: @scatter You can prove a negative. You just proved it. Proving something is "not hot" (a negative) would be done by proving that the opposite is true. That is IIRC falsifiability, and so a statement (negative or positive!) that you cannot prove is unfalsifiable. For example: I can prove that I did not die yesterday by being alive today. That is an event you know did not happen (is falsified) by the fact I am typing this to you. I cannot prove, however, that I did not think of a pink elephant yesterday. That is unfalsifiable.

Comment: @EricDuminil that one is technically unfalsifiable. It's practically, but not logically impossible for him to have done so. Given that Pluto is a planet that can be walked on, George Washington was capable of walking, it is possible that George Washington walked on Pluto. It isn't plausible, nor likely, nor probable, and unless someone can show proof to the contrary we can safely presume he did not, in fact, bestride fair Pluto. But we can't *prove* he didn't. Who knows what bored aliens decided to show the man.

Comment: @JustAnotherSoul Ahah. Thanks for the serious answer to my tongue-in-cheek comment. I don't know then, George Washington never flew to Sirius in less than 3 years?

Answer (score 10):

You don't need proof.  If you believe someone owes you, just bill them for whatever you think is owed.

The burden of proof is on them to show they paid. On the off-chance they have, any competent business will have no trouble showing this.

**However, that should not be happening**.  Sometimes, that is a routine issue that is easily explained, like paper bills and paper checks crossing in the mail.  If you are encountering this situation in *other* cases, then there is a serious problem with your bookkeeping system.  Your own business records are not in order.   You need to get them in order before you bill anyone else.  Otherwise you will make a fool of yourself with your clients, and accounting departments will become reluctant to pay *any* of your bills.

Comment: Is the word "dun" one that any business owner should recognise? I am not, and I do not. Just wondering whether this requires clarification.

Comment: @TomW I understand what "dun" means in the context, but it is certainly not a word I would use myself.  I suspect it may be regional.  (See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dun entry 3, meaning 1.)

Comment: @TomW okay.  . . .

Comment: @Harper - missed an opportunity there. Ok, I'm dun now.

Comment: Here is my bill to @Harper for 1 million (what ever) now prove you don't owe me... This answer is wrong, the proposed debtor has no obligation to prove they do not owe money. On the other hand if the debt was due, and both parties agree it was due, the debtor should be able to show it was paid.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Keep in mind here, "proof" is only 51%, not "beyond reasonable doubt".   And yeah, that's actually a very common scam.  It's done because the accounting dept. either says no, or just pays it if they're not on the ball, which many aren't.  So it's a no-risk gambit.  More often it's done as part of an unordered-goods scam, for even more deniability.  See also Molski... Or Righthaven/Prenda ... Statistically only about 1 person in 1000 will stand up and fight back.

Comment: @JamesJenkins As to your bill, "Dear Mr. Jenkins.  Our records show we did not order any such item.  Goodbye."  <D&D dungeon master> *What will you do?*

Comment: @JamesJenkins You're mixing two different articles of proof here: 1) Did you ever owe a debt?  and 2) Did you already pay that debt in full?  OP's question clearly assumes that #1 is not in dispute.

Comment: @Harper You're showing a little too much confidence in the client.  *Many* clients will claim to have paid invoices they did not pay.  *Very difficult* clients - (ahem) deadbeats - may say things like "Prove I didn't pay you!"  OP could easily be in that situation, even if his records are perfect.

Comment: @tbrookside yeah, but the foundation of my thinking is in the answer. Just bill  them.  (A client's protest that he paid, plus $6, will buy a small coffee at Starbucks).  What matters is documentation.  For instance, an image of a cashed check with the invoice number written on the check memo line, is pretty conclusive.  *That's why you write invoice numbers on memo lines / Paypal note fields, etc.* All of it is posturing for the ultimate endgame, court.

Comment: Slightly late, but i'm assuming to "dun" is part of the dunning process - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning_(process). Essentially the process of collecting money thats overdue from a company

Answer (score 2):

If the client is not willing to cooperate, which I'm assuming is the case, there is no way to prove it definitively. Any sane authority should agree that the burden of proof rests on the client to prove that it *has* been paid. If the client is unable to produce such proof, he is generally judged as not having paid.

> Also payer's (client's) bank account statement, with missing relevant line(s), is insufficient as well because the payer could have paid with a different bank account.

And he could have also paid you cash, so even all their statements will be insufficient. However, you could produce your own statement in all accounts in which you receive payment, to show that no payment has been *received* by you.

Another way would be to get the client to confirm on record that they have not paid.

Comment: Of course, you don't need to prove it *definitively*, just "on the balance of probabilites" (that is, it is more likely that the client has not paid than that the client has paid).

Comment: RE "Any sane authority should agree that the burden of proof rests on the client to prove that it has been paid." I actually have a bit of problem with this in that I think there is also at least equally as much responsibility to prove that the goods, service or whatever is being paid for has actually been delivered or completed.

Comment: @R.Hamilton Sure, and that's a defense the client is welcome to raise.